# Python regex to parse router config

Tags: python, regex

I can't seem to get my regex to work quite right.  There are several edge cases that I can't seem handle.
A standard router config looks like this:

```
interface Vlan1

  description

  ip address 1.2.3.4/30

!
```

The interface starts with 'interface NAME' and ends with !.  I would like my regex to capture the interface name 'Vlan1' and the ip '1.2.3.4/30'

Here is what I have that almost works: `re.compile(r"interface (.*)(?:[^!].*\n){1,50}?  (?:no )?ip(?: v4| v6)? address(.*?)\n")`

Edge cases:

- I don't know how many lines the ip will be from the interface name (50 should be enough)
- sometimes the ip address line might be: 'ip v4 address', 'ip v6 address', or 'no ip address'

I think I have all of that working, but when there is an interface like below:

```
interface Vlan2
!
```

It breaks everything.  Is there something else I can be doing to capture between 'interface' and '!'?

Comment: Your `re.compile(` call is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the non-optional parts  , `ip` and  `address`, your regex doesn't match the *empty* interface section. Because of its complexity, I started anew and suggest this simpler one:

```
re.compile(r"^interface (\w+)(?:[^!]*?address (\S+))?.*?!", re.M+re.S)
```

With your two examples, `findall()` would yield `[('Vlan1', '1.2.3.4/30'), ('Vlan2', '')]`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I will have both of those examples in the same file (and if vlan2 is first it doesn't work).  But I should be able to get something working with this.

Comment: I'm sure you'd be able to, but I couldn't leave my error uncorrected - I modified the pattern slightly. Thanks for mentioning!

Answer (score 0):

This regex works based on your example

```
interface (\w+)$[\w\s]*?address ([\d.\/]+)
```

It returns 2 groups,

```
Vlan1
1.2.3.4/30
```

See it working on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ePFkGs/1).